# Finding $cdf$ of $V=Y/X$ given $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=e^{-y}I_{0<x<y}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ have the following joint density:
>
> $$ f_{X,Y}(x,y)=   \begin{cases}  e^{-y} & 0 \lt x \lt y \\ 0 &
>   otherwise  \end{cases} $$
>
> Give the $cdf$ of $V=Y/X$.

I would like to use the $cdf$ method.

I have

$$\begin{align*}
F_{V}(v) 
&= P(V\leq v) \\\\
&= P(Y/X \leq v) \\\\
&= P(Y \leq Xv) \\\\
\end{align*}$$

However, from here, I am having trouble setting up the double integral in such a way that the outside integral does not have limits in terms of $x$ or $y$.

In seems to me that $y\in(x,xv)$and $x\in(0,y)$ but both of these depend on $x$ and $y$.

Comment: The condition that $$0<x<y<xv$$ means that $$x>0\qquad\text{and then}\qquad x<y<vx$$ and also that $$y>0\qquad\text{and then}\qquad y/v<x<y$$ thus your probability is $$P(Y<vX)=\int_0^\infty\int_x^{vx}e^{-y}dydx$$ and also $$P(Y<vX)=\int_0^\infty\int_{y/v}^ye^{-y}dxdy$$ Pick up your choice... and rejoice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easiest to draw a picture of the region, and divide it into vertical strips (the first integral below) or horizontal strips (the second integral below).

$$\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \mathbf{1}\{y \le xv\} f(x,y) \mathop{dy} \mathop{dx}
= \int_0^\infty \int_0^y \mathbf{1}\{y \le xv\} f(x,y) \mathop{dx} \mathop{dy} $$

From here, you can place the indicator function into the limits of the integral by
$$\int_0^\infty \int_x^{xv} f(x,y) \mathop{dy} \mathop{dx} = \int_0^\infty \int_{y/v}^y f(x,y) \mathop{dx} \mathop{dy}$$

Note that the above is valid only for $v \ge 1$, which makes sense since $Y/X \ge 1$ with probability $1$.

---

Alternatively you could directly note
$$\{0<x<y\} \cap \{y \le xv\} = \{y>0\} \cap \{y/v \le x < y\} = \{x > 0\} \cap \{x < y \le vx\}.$$

Comment: I obtained $F_V(v) = 1-\frac{1}{v}$ from the second double integral provided, but got an error in wolfram alpha from the first one.

Comment: This sounds correct since $F_V(1)=0$ and $F_V(\infty)$ approaches $1$.

Comment: Just do it by hand, @Remy.  $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\int_x^{xv} e^{-y}\mathrm dy\mathrm d x ~{=\int_0^\infty (e^{-x}-e^{-xv})\mathrm d x \\= 1-\tfrac 1v}$